# How to autoconnect kali to android for bluetooth tethering

Tags: linux, android, bluetooth, kali-linux

I'm trying to connect my rasberry pi zero 2 running kali-pitail to my phone via bluetooth for insternet and ssh access.
I can make this work with the graphical bluetooth manager, but opening vnc every time I want to do this is getting on my nerves. Please help me automate this or at least make it work thru command line (a.k.a ssh). The kali pitail docks were pretty limited so I didn't quite get it working the way it should be done by the docks in here. https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-pi-tail/ and here https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/raspberry-pi-zero-w-pi-tail/

So the thing works when I use manual gui app to configure it, but it would be much more convinient to automate.

here are my ifconfig and routes from the pi-tail

```
`bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:cc:4c:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38  bytes 6612 (6.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 360 (360.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

bnep1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fecc:4c1f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:cc:4c:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19  bytes 3500 (3.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 1719 (1.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.41.1  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 192.168.41.3
        inet6 fe80::88d1:fbff:fe99:248e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8a:d1:fb:99:24:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 2562 (2.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.97.161  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.97.255
        inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe89:69c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:89:69:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 823  bytes 62103 (60.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 570  bytes 109134 (106.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`└─$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.97.174  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.41.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 pan0
192.168.97.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0`
```